# blank screen appears when click on UILabel in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uilabel

i'm trying to open iPhone call screen with selected number when click on UIlabel which is hyperlink in swift.

a blank screen appears for 1 second and goes. No iPhone call screen appears. Don't know what is wrong in my code.

Code in viewDidLoad

```
let strPhone = "080 2854 2105"

let attributedPhoneStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string:strPhone, attributes:[NSLinkAttributeName: NSURL(string: "http://aerospace.honeywell.com")!])

lblPhoneContact.attributedText = attributedPhoneStr

lblPhoneContact.userInteractionEnabled = true

let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("labelPressed"))

lblPhoneContact.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
```

Function labelPressed

```
func labelPressed() {      

let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "tel://08028542105")!

UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)

}
```

what is wrong or missing in my code.
I tried running on my iPhone device.

Answer (score 0):

for swift use

```
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "telprompt:08028542105")!
```

instead of

```
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "tel://08028542105")!
```

Comment: No. Using "telprompt://" will invoke the request to call, however using "tel://" will just call the number directly without prompt request.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the GCD's dispatch_async to invoke the "openURL" method:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should omit the // from the uri - I.e. It should just be

```
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "tel:08028542105")!
```